# On the tags [viewpoint] and [grammatical-person]

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that we have a tag [viewpoint](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewpoint), currently on 104 questions, with a tag wiki reading:

> Questions about grammatical persons (first person, third person, etc.) and how to use them.

and the tag [grammatical-person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-person), currently on 76 questions, with a tag wiki:

> Questions about the point of view of the narrator of a work.

From the tag wiki, each of them seems to describe exactly what the other's name says.

This could be a sign that they really should be synonyms. Or they are actually intended to be different, but either the tag name or the tag wiki doesn't state the intent correctly.

As additional fact to consider, the tag wiki of [pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov) says:

> Use the 'viewpoint' tag if your question is about the grammatical viewpoints (first, third, etc.), which to use, or how to use them.

In any case I think something should be done about it, though I don't know what.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to see us keep/create one tag for all of these and create a synonym or two to make them easy to find.  I am very open to which tag name is primary and how many synonyms there are.

I would dump [grammatical-person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-person) altogether and retag.

While there is a distinction between the grammar of point of view and the concept, there is so much overlap that I don't see any use in keeping them separate tags.  People asking about the grammar can additionally tag with [grammar](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) and people asking about the concept can additionally tag with [narrator](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator) or [narration](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration) or something else that works.

For example:

1. [point-of-view](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-of-view) with a synonym of [pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov).
2. If people prefer the wording, we can keep [viewpoint](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewpoint) as the primary, with [pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov) as a synonym.
3. We might have [pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov) as primary and put [point-of-view](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-of-view) *or* [viewpoint](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewpoint) as a synonym (we don't need both because anyone searching for "view" or "point" will find them).

My preference is in the order specified above.

Comment: We should absolutely have [tag:point-of-view] instead of [tag:pov]. Though both are clear the longer one is a much better tag name. I think we should just have [tag:point-of-view] and merge/synonymise everything else to it.

Comment: @linksassin If we were starting tags from scratch, yes.  But I'd keep pov just as a synonym, because people are used to it.

Comment: Oh sorry that's what I meant. Have the tag be called [tag:point-of-view] with a synonym of [tag:pov] that we map to it. I should have been clearer.

Comment: @linksassin Well in that case, I completely agree with you :-D

Comment: We talked about it, and then nothing happened. And now you're a mod, so you can do it yourself. :)

Comment: Oh, just realised we also have a [tag:third-person] tag. That one should definitely be merged into [tag:viewpoint] or [tag:grammatical-person] or whatever.

Comment: @Galastel I've been wondering about these tags and what we should do about them.  Yeah, let's work to clean them up in the next week.  We also have a [tag:first-person] tag.  Not sure if any of these should be separate or not.

Comment: [tag:first-person] and [tag:third-person] should definitely be merged into one tag that's about both. The way I see it, we need one tag that's about use of first person and third person, and one tag that's about POV.

Comment: Found another related tag: [tag:perspective].

Answer (score 5):

I *think* that [grammatical-person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-person) was meant to be more about the grammar of the text, and would be more suited to tech writing and academic writing questions. [viewpoint](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewpoint) would be more suited to fiction and the effects of first person on a narrative, head-hopping, etc.

Clearly we'd need to update the tag wikis, and it's probably time for a retagging effort. I'd be happy to do this if we get a consensus on how to handle it.

Comment: FWIW, as a technical writer I would never think to look for a tag named grammatical-person.